# What to import to use string type on actionscript?

Tags: string, flash, actionscript, import

Im a total noob on actionscript, NEVER used it, but Im compiling a Unity project to flash, and for doing browser<-> javascript communication I nned to make a hackish thing providing a class on .as code..
The unity is acusing it doesnt know the type string:
"Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: string."

Heres my code, note I dont have even a flash compiler, Im using notepad++, so Im on a minefield, dont know the language and cant debug it.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.system.Security;

import global.SCORMInsideActionScriptFunctions;

public class BrowserCommunicator
{
    public static function callFromJavascript() : void
    {
        trace("Javascript successfully called ActionScript function.");
    }

    // callback to register:
    public static function GetSessionTime() : string
    {
        return SCORMInsideActionScriptFunctions.GetSessionTime()
    }


    //Sets up an ExternalInterface callback and calls a Javascript function.
    public static function TestCommunication() : void
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            try
            {
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("callFromJavascript", callFromJavascript);

                // mine:
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("GetSessionTime", GetSessionTime);


            }
            catch (error:SecurityError)
            {
                trace("A SecurityError occurred: " + error.message);
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
                trace("An Error occurred: " + error.message);
            }

            ExternalInterface.call('calledFromActionScript');
        }
        else
        {
            trace("External interface not available");
        }
    }

    public static function FlushData_ServerToCache() : void
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            // calls the java function here:
            ExternalInterface.call('flushData');
        }
        else
        {
            trace("External interface not available");
        }
    }

    public static function SubmitData_CacheToServer() : void
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call('submitData');
        }
        else
        {
            trace("External interface not available");
        }
    }

    public static function SetData_AppToCache( field : string, data : string) : void
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call('setData', field, data);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("External interface not available");
        }
    }

    public static function GetData_CacheToApp( field : string ) : string
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            return ExternalInterface.call('getData', field);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("External interface not available");
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write *String* instead of *string* :)

Comment: you gotta be kidding me =____=

Comment: hey, notepad++ is coloring my data:String var, is it a reserved keyword or what?

Comment: String is top level class and you don't need to import it.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html

Comment: its the data word that is being colored..I meant